# 'AM' or 'PM' in the time format?

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to modify the default.html demo in full calendar-2.3.2 so that it displays 'AM' or 'PM' in the time format.

All I seem to get is 'A' or 'P' on the calendar displayed.

How do i do this please? I am struggling with the docs somewhat.

Answer (score 6):

I finally found the answer to this myself, should anyone else find themselves in the same predicament:

timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a'

will render as (for example) 7:30pm

Comment: or capital 'A' for PM & AM output